# JS how to get a variable name inside of a objective variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters

I am a beginner of js. I tried find a solution over internet but I couldnt.

Is there a way to know what is the name of a variable??

On below, i will be the value of each parameter......, Please advice!!!

```
Object = { a: xxx, b : xxx };


for(var i in Object ) { if(/* i`s variable name is 'a'*/){ /* do something*/ }  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your example:

```
obj = { a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb' };

for (var i in obj) {
    if (i === 'a') {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Another method without looping through the object:

```
obj = { a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb' };

if ('a' in obj) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: @pst yes, no need to loop over the items in `obj`.